# Why list.__repr__ does not use list.__getitem__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have overriden the `__getitem__` of the built-in type `list`:

```
class my_list(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index, *args, **kwargs):
        value = super().__getitem__(index, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(index, slice): 
            return [v**2 for v in value]
        return value**2
```

and have created a new instance of it:

```
a = my_list((1, 2, 3, 4))
```

both `repr(a)` and `print(a)` outputs the same unmodified `[1, 2, 3, 4]` value without calling overriden `__getitem__`. I would expect to get `[1, 4, 9, 16]` in both of these cases.

However, `a[2]`, `a[:]` calls `__getitem__` and the results are respectively `9` and `[1, 4, 9, 16]`. Just as expected.

How to override a single method in order to make consistent representations of my custom list? Or which methods do I have to override in order to cover all ways to retrieve the values of my custom list?

Comment: There is no single method to override, and there is no reason to expect there to be one.

Comment: You need to implement `__iter__` as well.

Answer (score 1):

> How to override a single method in order to make consistent representations of my custom list?

Specific implementations don't usually guarantee that a single method will be available for things like this, especially builtins, often for efficiency reasons.

If you want to ensure everything goes through a single method or known codepath, instead of a subtype create a *wrapper* sequence (using [Sequence or MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)), that way you know exactly what is implemented where, and you can ultimately delegate to the wrapped object as and when you want.